# Spring/Hibernate No session found for current thread (config)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to understand the configuration for Spring and Hibernate together.  Every time I make calls to the database, I get a no session found for current thread error in my console (doesn't stop the app since I just create a new session if it can't find one).  I have a standard STS Maven setup.  The below is how I have the configuration currently setup.  However, if I take everything in the root-context.xml and put it at the bottom of servlet-context.xml, it works without any errors.  So I'm guessing something within servlet-context.xml is "overwriting" something and not taking the @Transactional annotations I have on my service.  But how do you config around that?

root-context.xml

```
    <!-- Configure JDBC Connection-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Steven\Desktop\Programming\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\bin\mydb" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure Hibernate 4 Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.css.genapp" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>format</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.css.genapp" />
```

Comment: Are you loading root-context.xml in web.xml ? if not use this <import resource="root-context.xml"/> in your servlet-context.xml

Comment: Yes its being loaded in web.xml.  I know its pulling in from root-context.xml since that is where the database config is, but it doesn't take the Transaction Annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define component scan on both servlet-context.xml and root-context.xml

- root-context.xml: for service, repository...
- servlet-context.xml: for controller and web relate component.

Hope it can help. You can check detail on this sample [Spring, JPA and hibernate integration](http://devjav.com/springjpa-hibernate-integration/)

Comment: this is correct,you normally specify controllers in servlet, and all the rest in root. You match via regexs, or dir structre

Comment: Yep, seemed to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your Hibernate configuration you configured `<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>` Like this.

Remove the property because it really breaks proper session/transaction management in spring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import root-context.xml since only servlet-context.xml will be read by dispatcher servlet. Add the following line in your servlet-context.xml :